# Problem when trying to send a query consists of 2 command to Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get the following error when trying to DELETE from my tables:
Error: DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID='K0D4iJ0aEzHJh03'; DELETE FROM table2 WHERE ID='K0D4iJ0aEzHJh03'

I've tried to put the query to workbench, and it's working flawless. If I try to send only 1 line 
DELETE from table1 WHERE ID='K0D4iJ0aEzHJh03';
OR
DELETE from table2 WHERE ID='K0D4iJ0aEzHJh03';
It's working flawless.

```
$sql="DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID='$ID';
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE ID='$ID'";
}
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Your request has been succesfully made.";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: why you using 2 delete continously?

Comment: You should not be executing 2 queries at the same time. This is a terrible idea. Execute them one after another, and if they depend on each other, use a transaction.

Comment: `$conn->error` doesn't give you anything because your connection is `$con`.  The `query` function only supports one query at a time, and for good reason.

Comment: Well, I'm building a practice project right now, there's a lot more to learn about php. I check out prepared statements, and revise my code, thanks for constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do two deletes.  MySQL lets you delete from two tables at the same time:

```
DELETE t1, t2
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN
         table2 t2
         ON t1.ID = t2.id
    WHERE t1.ID = ?;  -- use parameters!
```

In practice, though, you probably want cascading delete constraints.

EDIT:

If the `id` may not exist in both tables:

```
DELETE t1, t2
    FROM (SELECT ? as ID) i LEFT JOIN
         table1 t1 
         ON t1.id = i.id LEFT JOIN
         table2 t2
         ON t2.ID = i.id;
```

Comment: Would this work if the id exist only in one of the tables?

Comment: @Dharman . . . You can use a `LEFT JOIN`, if you know it is in one table.  I added an example where the `id` can not exist in either table.

Answer (score 0):

That's my solution now, I hope it looks better. Thanks for the help.

```
$del=$con->prepare("DELETE t1, t2
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.ID=t2.ID)
    WHERE t1.ID=?;");
    $del->bind_param("s", $ID); 
        $ID=$_POST["ID"];
        $del->execute();
        $del->close();
```